# Getting HWND of current Process

Tags: c++, c, winapi, windows

I have a process in c++ in which I am using window API. I want to get the HWND of own process. Kindly guide me how can I make it possible.

Comment: If it's your process, then aren't you the one who created the window in the first place? You should already have the handle.

Comment: I have handle, but the problem is i have different threads in my process I want that handle in those threads at different time.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's still not clear what you exactly want to do... could you describe better the situation?

Comment: A HWND is not a process handle. A process might have zero, one, or many windows, and each window has its own HWND. Without more information, your question doesn't make sense. Does the process have exactly one window?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269390/how-to-get-hwnd-of-window-opened-by-shellexecuteex-hprocess

Comment: Accessing window handles from threads other than the owning thread is asking for trouble. In general you should only ever modify windows from the owning thread.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are (incorrectly) assuming that a process has only a single HWND. This is not generally true, and therefore Windows can't offer an API to get it. A program could create two windows, and have two HWNDs as a result. OTOH, if your program creates only a single window, it can store that HWND in a global variable.

Answer (score 30):

If you're talking about getting a *process* handle, then it's not an `HWND` (which is a **w**i**nd**ow **h**andle), but a `HANDLE` (i.e., a kernel object handle); to retrieve a pseudo-handle relative to the current process, you can use [`GetCurrentProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683179%28VS.85%29.aspx) as the others explained.

On the other hand, if you want to obtain an `HWND` (a *window* handle) to the main window of your application, then you have to walk the existing windows with [`EnumWindows`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497(v=vs.85).aspx) and to check their ownership with [`GetWindowThreadProcessId`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633522%28VS.85%29.aspx), comparing the returned process ID with the one returned by [`GetCurrentProcessId`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683180%28VS.85%29.aspx). Still, in this case you'd better to save your main window handle in a variable when you create it instead of doing all this mess.

Anyhow, keep always in mind that not all handles are the same: `HANDLE`s and `HWND`s, in particular, are completely different beasts: the first ones are kernel handles (=handles to kernel-managed objects) and are manipulated with generic kernel-handles manipulation functions (`DuplicateHandle`, `CloseHandle`, ...), while the second ones are handles relative to the window manager, which is a completely different piece of the OS, and are manipulated with a different set of functions.

Actually, in theory an `HWND` may have the same "numeric" value of a `HANDLE`, but they would refer to completely different objects.

Answer (score 17):

#### Get your console window

```
GetConsoleWindow();
```

"The return value is a handle to the window used by the console associated with the calling process or NULL if there is no such associated console."

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683175(v=vs.85).aspx

#### Get other windows

`GetActiveWindow()` might **NOT** be the answer, but it could be useful

"The return value is the handle to the active window attached to the calling thread's message queue. Otherwise, the return value is NULL." > [msdn GetActiveWindow() docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646292(v=vs.85).aspx)

However, the graphical windows *are not* just popping up - ***so you should retrieve the handle from the place you/your app've created the window...*** e.g. `CreateWindow()` returns `HWND` handle so all you need is to save&retrieve it...

Answer (score 6):

The [`GetCurrentProcess()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683179(VS.85).aspx) function returns a pseudo-handle which refers to the current process.  This handle can be used in most Win32 API functions that take a process handle parameter.

The documentation contains more information about this pseudo-handle, including how to convert it to a real handle if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `HANDLE WINAPI GetCurrentProcess(void);` from Kernel32.dll.

See MSDN entry [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683179(v=VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score -1):

My example is not to deal with process, but maybe you need this:

```
HWND hwndList = GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDCL_COMBOBOX);
```

This returns HWND of the control specified by its `IDCL_COMBOBOX`.

Answer (score -2):

Here is another answer:

this->GetSafeHwnd();