# How to get hWnd of window opened by ShellExecuteEx.. hProcess?

Tags: c++, process, window, handle

This "simple" issue seems to be fraught with side issues.
  eg. Does the new process open multiple windows; Does it have a splash screen?
  Is there a simple way?  (I'm starting a new instance of Notepad++)

```
...
std::tstring  tstrNotepad_exe = tstrProgramFiles + _T("\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe");

SHELLEXECUTEINFO SEI={0};
sei.cbSize       = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
sei.fMask        = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
sei.hwnd         = hWndMe;  // This app's window handle
sei.lpVerb       = _T("open");
sei.lpFile       = tstrNotepad_exe.c_str();     
sei.lpParameters = _T(" -multiInst -noPlugins -nosession -notabbar ";   
sei.lpDirectory  = NULL;
sei.nShow        = SW_SHOW;
sei.hInstApp     = NULL;    
if( ShellExecuteEx(&sei) )
{ // I have sei.hProcess, but how best to utilize it from here?
}
...
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First use `WaitForInputIdle` to pause your program until the application has started and is waiting for user input (the main window should have been created by then), then use `EnumWindows` and `GetWindowThreadProcessId` to determine which windows in the system belong to the created process.

For example:

```
struct ProcessWindowsInfo
{
    DWORD ProcessID;
    std::vector<HWND> Windows;

    ProcessWindowsInfo( DWORD const AProcessID )
        : ProcessID( AProcessID )
    {
    }
};

BOOL __stdcall EnumProcessWindowsProc( HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam )
{
    ProcessWindowsInfo *Info = reinterpret_cast<ProcessWindowsInfo*>( lParam );
    DWORD WindowProcessID;

    GetWindowThreadProcessId( hwnd, &WindowProcessID );

    if( WindowProcessID == Info->ProcessID )
        Info->Windows.push_back( hwnd );

    return true;
}

....

if( ShellExecuteEx(&sei) )
{
    WaitForInputIdle( sei.hProcess, INFINITE );

    ProcessWindowsInfo Info( GetProcessId( sei.hProcess ) );

    EnumWindows( (WNDENUMPROC)EnumProcessWindowsProc,
        reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>( &Info ) );

    // Use Info.Windows.....
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jon... So short interval polling is the way to go... that makes sense :)

Comment: I'm working through your example now...  
and a PS to my previous comment: I just noticed in MSDN: WaitForInputIdle can be used at any time, not just during application startup.  
However, WaitForInputIdle waits only once for a process to become idle; subsequent WaitForInputIdle calls return immediately, whether the process is idle or busy.  
* It seems polling is not a good idea... I'll do a few tests.

Comment: You should only need to use WaitForInputIdle when the process is created. From then on, just poll the EnumWindows call to get the updated window list.

Comment: Fantastic :) neat and sweet! ... (but I don't have enough points to mark it up, (yet).

Comment: I used your code,and it works ok, but hProcess is always 0 after ShellExecuteEx finishes.  What gives?

Comment: I know this is ancient, but @ john : your process must be started with the `SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS` flag

Comment: `WaitForInputIdle` doesn't do what you think it does. See [WaitForInputIdle should really be called WaitForProcessStartupComplete](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100325-00/?p=14493) and [WaitForInputIdle waits for any thread, which might not be the thread you care about](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100326-00/?p=14483). Use [WinEvents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373889.aspx) instead to monitor window creation.