# HINSTANCE to HWND

Tags: c++, winapi

I use ShellExecute to create a new app instance from my current app. I want to get the HWND of that app. Is it possible to get HWND from HINSTANCE or I need to use EnumWindows?

Comment: [The return value is cast as an HINSTANCE for backward compatibility with 16-bit Windows applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153.aspx). It is not a true `HINSTANCE`, however. The only thing that can be done with the returned `HINSTANCE` is to cast it to an `int` and compare it with the value `32` or one of the error codes below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you're right, you need to enum your windows

[this question will help you further](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269390/how-to-get-hwnd-of-window-opened-by-shellexecuteex-hprocess)

Answer (score 6):

An application does not have a single `HWND`. Each window within the app has its own handle, an `HWND`.

You will need to use [`EnumWindows()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633497%28VS.85%29.aspx) or one of its friends.