# Get list of all processes windows name

Tags: c++, c, windows

I am currently using the following code to get the processID of every process running.

```
WTS_PROCESS_INFO* pWPIs = NULL;
DWORD dwProcCount = 0;
if(WTSEnumerateProcesses(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, NULL, 1, &pWPIs, &dwProcCount))
{
    //Go through all processes retrieved
    for(DWORD i = 0; i < dwProcCount; i++)
    {
        //pWPIs[i].pProcessName = process file name only, no path!
        //pWPIs[i].ProcessId = process ID
        //pWPIs[i].SessionId = session ID, if you need to limit it to the logged in user processes
        //pWPIs[i].pUserSid = user SID that started the process
    }
}

//Free memory
if(pWPIs)
{
    WTSFreeMemory(pWPIs);
    pWPIs = NULL;
}
```

I would also like to get the Window title to each of these processes if they have one. I am only interested in the process in my current session so I will filter out all processes based on session ID. If they are my session then I would like to get the Window Title.

So for example, if I ran this code with 10 notepads open I would see

```
notepad.exe
notepad.exe
notepad.exe
notepad.exe
notepad.exe
notepad.exe
...
```

But I want to get the title so that I know which notepad has which file open.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2531840/4641116

Comment: Are you saying the answer is with EnumWindows?

Answer (score 0):

### 1) HWND

### 2) Tasklist (call a system command and take the output)

1. You can find the HWND of the windows (one process may have many windows though) and then GetWindowText(hwnd).

Something like: [Get hwnd by process id c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11711417/get-hwnd-by-process-id-c)

```
HWND g_HWND=NULL;
BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProcMy(HWND hwnd,LPARAM lParam)
{
    DWORD lpdwProcessId;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd,&lpdwProcessId);
    if(lpdwProcessId==lParam)
    {
        g_HWND=hwnd;
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProcMy,m_ProcessId);
```

Then you have to call:

```
 GetWindowText(g_hwnd, title, nMax);



 int GetWindowTextA(
 HWND  hWnd,
 LPSTR lpString,
 int   nMaxCount
);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowtexta

### 2) Tasklist

With the WINDOWTITLE parameter and a wildcard * (or what's needed)

[How to get the window title of running application with command-line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52597795/how-to-get-the-window-title-of-running-application-with-command-line/52599021)