# Managing child process from separated thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

I have a main application that runs another application (exe) in a seperate process. To avoid confusing the user, the application window of the new process should be modal to my main application window.

So far I tried to run my application with **ShellExecuteEx** and wait with **WaitForSingleObject** for the process to finish. Bu this results in a frozen main window. I therefore put the ShellExecuteEx call into a seperate thread in my main application. Now The main windows is no longer frozen, but responsive for new user interaction. The child application additionaly continues to run, even when the main application already stopped.

How can I make the child process modal to my main application?

Here the code I call from a seperate thread in the main application:

```
SHELLEXECUTEINFO ShExecInfo = {0};
ShExecInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
ShExecInfo.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
ShExecInfo.hwnd = NULL;
ShExecInfo.lpVerb = L"";
ShExecInfo.lpFile = L"LicenseViewer.exe";       
ShExecInfo.lpParameters = NULL; 
ShExecInfo.lpDirectory = NULL;
ShExecInfo.nShow = SW_SHOW;
ShExecInfo.hInstApp = NULL; 
ShellExecuteEx(&ShExecInfo);
WaitForSingleObject(ShExecInfo.hProcess,INFINITE);
LPDWORD returncode;
GetExitCodeProcess(ShExecInfo.hProcess,returncode);
int value = static_cast<int>(*returncode);
```

**edit:**

As suggested by AdrianMcCarthy I called SetParent() to set my main window as the parent of the child process window. I got the window handle of the child process by using the solution postet here: [How to get hWnd of window opened by ShellExecuteEx.. hProcess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269390/how-to-get-hwnd-of-window-opened-by-shellexecuteex-hprocess)
The child window now apears infront of the main window (z-order seems fine) and terminates when the main window terminates.

Unfortunately I have several new issues now.

1. The window size of the child window is limited to the size of the main window. The child window cannot pass the bounds of the main window without beeing cut.
2. I can still interact with the main window.

Is there some way to fix theese issues?

Comment: Use `CreateProcess` instead of `ShellExecute` to create child process and to terminate it when necessary. Your question is not related to Qt at all.

Comment: When the child process creates its main window, have it set the parent process's window as the modal owner. (Modality will disable the main window, and the ownership gets the z-order and click forwarding right.)

Comment: How can I set the modal owner?

Comment: Specify your window in `ShExecInfo.hwnd`, or have the child process obtain your app's window through other means and assign it as the parent when creating its own window. Also, use `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects()` instead of `WaitForSingleObject()` so you can detect pending messages so you know when to pump the calling thread's message queue.

Comment: @RemyLebeau:  That's mostly right, but the ShExecInfo.hwnd is for the parent of any dialog boxes that the shell might need to show while attempting to start the child process.  It won't set the parent (or owner) of the window(s) created by the child process itself.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy: perhaps, in which case the parent window has to be communicated to the child process through command line or IPC, or the child process has to hunt for the parent window manually.  Either way, it can then pass the parent window to `CreateWindow/Ex()` or `SetParent()`.  But that assumes the poster has access to change the source of the child process.  Otherwise the poster is likely SOL, unless he calls `SetParent()` himself after `ShellExecute()` (or `CreateProcess()`) exits, in which case the parent app is hunting for the child process's window.

Comment: If you can't change the child app, the best you can do (which is probably sub-optimal) is to disable your main window while waiting for the child process to exit (using MsgWaitForMultipleObjects as previously suggested) and then re-enable it again.  This gets the modality mostly right, but doesn't properly solve the z-order.