# change size and/or position of Windows Control Panel programatically

Tags: c++, windows, windows-7

I'm opening the Windows Control Panel programatically using ShellExecute():

```
TCHAR strParameter[MAX_PATH];
wsprintf(strParameter, _T("shell32.dll, Control_RunDLL \"%ws\""), strApp);
HINSTANCE result = ShellExecute(NULL, _T("open"), _T("rundll32.exe"), strParameter, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL) ;
```

Now I would like to manipulate the Control Panel window by changing its size or its position.

I know that once you get a window handle you can use [SetWindowPos()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

The problem is that I couldn't find any way to get that handle in the case of the Control Panel. I can't enumerate based on Window Title or Window Class because I know neither one or the other.

Has someone already done this with Windows 7 ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get hWnd of window opened by ShellExecuteEx.. hProcess?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269390/how-to-get-hwnd-of-window-opened-by-shellexecuteex-hprocess)

Comment: I don't think so: I also tried to use CreateProcess() instead of ShellEexecute() so that I could get a PID to use for enumeration, but it doesn't help. I suspect the reason is that the process is rundll32.exe (command-line is: rundll32.exe shell32.dll, Control_RunDLL), but the Control Panel window is probably not linked to rundll32.exe process, rather to explorer.exe (?). But enumerating all windows of explorer.exe would also not help because I don't know what is the name or class of the Control Panel window anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the correct way using an enumeration of all windows:

```
BOOL CALLBACK FindWindowsByTitle(HWND hwnd,LPARAM lParam)
{
    LaunchApplication * thisClass = reinterpret_cast<LaunchApplication *>(lParam);
    TCHAR windowName[MAX_PATH] = {0};
    int windowNameLength = 0;
    LRESULT result = SendMessage(hwnd, WM_GETTEXT, MAX_PATH, LPARAM(windowName));
    windowNameLength = _tcslen(windowName);
    if(windowNameLength)
    {
            if (StrStrI(windowName, (TCHAR *)thisClass->getWndName()))
            {
                // found window name containing BT value
                return FALSE;
            }
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

Then the main issue is localization of windows title: if you need to have thos code works for Control Panel, you want thisClass->getWndName() to return a string that depends on your country or locale.

Answer (score 0):

If the suggested duplicate doesn't work, this is possible with the `FindWindow` function.

Note that the Control Panel may have a couple names, depending on it's view, so you'll have to check the different options.

```
HWND cp = FindWindow(0, "Control Panel");
if(!cp){
    cp = FindWindow(0, "All Control Panel Items");
}
if(!cp){
    // Control Panel not open
}
```

Note that this method may fail if you have, say, a folder named "Control Panel" open.

Comment: Hello,this doesn't work either. FindWindow() is notoriously unreliable when you use the window title field, I couldn't even find a Notepad window handle with it ! Using the Window Class works better but in the case of the Control Panel I could not identify that class.

Comment: Really? Did you just search for Notepad, or did you look for "Untitled - Notepad" (Assuming it's a new Notepad window)? I've never had a problem with it, as long as the window existed, and was unique.

Comment: I use "Untitled - Notepad" without success. Anyways you can't use this method either for Control Panel.