# How to launch Chrome maximized via shell execution?

Tags: c++, windows, google-chrome

I am launching Chrome with the `app="http://..."` parameter (a Chrome application shortcut) via C++. Now it seems to open with a size of roughly 400x800 which is crazy. I'd like to open it maximized or at least have it remember the size.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: How are you launching it? (`CreateProcess`, `ShellExecute`, ...)

Comment: I'm using `_popen` (Windows).

Comment: @Matteo: but if you know how to make it work with `CreateProcess` or some other way I'm happy to hear!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't mind using the default browser (which, in my opinion, is the best option) instead of forcing the use of Chrome, you can simply open your URL with [`ShellExecute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) specifying that you want the window to be maximized:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <Shellapi.h>
// requires linking towards Shell32.lib

// ...

if(ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "http://www.stackoverflow.com", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED)<=32)
{
    /* an error occurred */
}
```

---

> I must open Chrome, and I have its path known in a variable. I also need to specify one parameter. Is this a problem?

Well, in this case it's better to use [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
#include <windows.h>

// ...

// Assuming that the path to chrome is inside the chromePath variable
// and the URL inside targetURL
// Important: targetURL *must be* a writable buffer, not a string literal
// (otherwise the application may crash on Unicode builds)
PROCESS_INFORMATION processInformation;
STARTUPINFO startupInfo;
memset(&processInformation, 0, sizeof(processInformation));
memset(&startupInfo, 0, sizeof(startupInfo));
startupInfo.cb = sizeof(startupInfo);
startupInfo.wShowWindow = SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED;

BOOL result= CreateProcess(chromePath, targetURL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, NULL, NULL, &startupInfo, &processInformation);

if(result)
{
    WaitForSingleObject( processInformation.hProcess, INFINITE );
    CloseHandle( processInformation.hProcess );
    CloseHandle( processInformation.hThread );
}
else
{
    // An error happened
}
```

Notice that you can try to specify a default size/posizion for the window using the `dwX`/`dwY`/`dwXSize`/`dwYSize` members of the [`STARTUPINFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686331%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure, but I'm not sure if Chrome respects these settings.

Comment: I *must* open Chrome, and I have its path known in a variable. I also need to specify one parameter. Is this a problem?

Comment: You could re-adapt this code to work with it, but if you have a specific path to it it's better to use `CreateProcess` and keep the shell out of it. I'll post the code in 2 mins.

Comment: I'm not getting it to work. I can make it work `SW_SHOWMINIMIZED` etc, but with `SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED` it just does not work. Nothing happens. If I try to resize afterwards the process creation I get access violations. Code: http://pastie.org/private/la9i5apucfy8b8psuxw8pg

Comment: Your code is filled with errors: first of all, I *explicitly wrote* that the second parameter *must be* a writable buffer, and the fact that the parameter is non-const is exactly for that reason. You shouldn't just put a `const_cast` there, but pass a modifiable `char *` or copy the `const char *` you have into a buffer. Then, into the `if`, you are leaking handles by not closing them. But most importantly, it makes no sense to cast `hProcess` to an `HWND`: it's a *process handle*, not a *window* handle, it's obvious that you get access violations!

Comment: @Matteo: Thank you for your feedback. Here is the updated code: http://pastie.org/private/apyb0poqqmoj3koo25dq
Chrome does not seem to detect the SW_SHOWMINIMIZED/MAXIMIZED values. Is there something that you would recommend?

Comment: @Stanislav: there are still all the errors I said before besides the wrong usage of the handle. Still, if Chrome does not listen to `SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED`, you should try to get the top-level window from the process handle you have, which is more or less summarized in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620409/getting-hwnd-of-current-process/2620522#2620522) reply.

Answer (score -1):

--start-maximized should do the trick.
Taken from http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/
Haven't tested it myself though..